# ValueError in Python with for loop

Tags: python, file-read

I need to make a function that returns certain lines in a file based on a list of numbers but I keep getting `ValueError: Mixing iteration and read methods would lose data.` Any suggestions?

```
with open(path) as f:
    for line in f:
        if i in lst:
            a = f.readline()
            ans += [a.strip()]
            i += 1
        else:
            f.readline()
            i += 1
```

Comment: One line 3, what is `i`?

Comment: variable that starts at 0

Comment: i have a text file and a list of numbers. I need to return only the lines corresponding to those numbers.

Comment: Is the list sorted?

Comment: You can use either `for line in f:` or `.readline()`, not both.

Comment: Yes the list is sorted

Answer (score 2):

Iterating the lines in the `f` should suffice:

```
with open(path) as f:
    for i, line in enumerate(f):
       if i in lst:
           # do something
           ans += [line.strip()]
```

This assumes `path`, `lst` and `ans` are defined.  Since you are iterating the lines in the file, you don't need `f.readlines()`, and you don't need an incrementer.  Just use `enumerate`.

Note, serial list concatenations (i.e. the last line) are inefficient.  Depending on what you are trying to do, look into [list comprehensions](http://treyhunner.com/2015/12/python-list-comprehensions-now-in-color/), which are faster and traditionally more Pythonic.  Consider @Burhan Khalid's approach.

Answer (score 1):

You can simply this with a list comprehension:

```
def filter_file(filename, line_numbers):
   with open(filename) as f:
      return [line.strip() for idx,line in enumerate(f) if idx in line_numbers]

result = filter_file('some_file.txt', [1,5,7])
```

If your `line_numbers` is not 0-indexed (1 is the first line), then you need to adjust the loop:

```
return [line.strip() for idx,line in enumerate(f) if idx+1 in line_numbers]
```

Answer (score 0):

You are mixing `for line in f` and `f.readline()` which means you will be reading more lines than you probably intend to. To avoid this, try changing your code to something like this:

```
with open(path) as f:
    while True:
        if i in lst:
            a = f.readline()
            if not a:
                break
            ans += [a.strip()]
            i += 1
        else:
            a = f.readline()
            if not a:
                break
            i += 1
```

This way, only your `readline` calls will read data from the file.